# populated objects doesn't seem to show up in postman's response body

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, postman

i have populated the query result with the user's name and avatar

```
  router.get("/me", auth, async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const profile = await Profile.findOne({
          user: req.user.id,
        }).populate("user", ["name", "avatar"]);

    if (!profile) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "there is no profile for this user" });
    }
    res.json({ profile });
    console.log("profile", profile);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});
```

When I make a get request to this url in Postman app, the user property of the response i get in the Postman is this:

`"user":"a string"`,

But when i check inside the console it is this:

```
 user: {
        id:"a string",
        name:"username",
        avatar:"avatarUrl"
       }
```

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/node-js-forked-j340i?file=/src/index.js
Something to do with Postman maybe? You could try reinstalling it.